# How to add a tag based on a column value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, case

I'm trying to join two tables and select certain columns to display in the output including a 'flag' if a certain transaction amount is greater than or equal to 100. The flag would return a 1 if it is, else null.

I thought I could achieve this using a CASE in my SELECT but it only returns one record every time since it returns the first record that meets this condition. How do I just create this 'FLAG' column during my join easily?

```
SELECT payment_id, amount, type, 
CASE
    WHEN amount >= 100 THEN 1
    ELSE NULL
END AS flag
FROM trans JOIN customers  ON (user_id = cust_id)
JOIN bank ON (trans.bank = bank.id)
WHERE (error is false)
```

I expect an output such as:

```
payment_id amount type  flag
1          81      3     NULL
2          104     2     1
3          150     2     1
4          234     1     1
```

However, I'm only getting the first record such as:

```
payment_id amount type  flag
2          104     2     1
```

Comment: There is clearly something missing that you have not shown us. You are filtering data out in a certain way. Perhaps posting more of your data would help.

Comment: *it returns the first record that meets this condition* what condition? CASE does not restrict the returned rows. The conditions in the ON clauses and the WHERE clause do.

Comment: Please use following code
    SELECT payment_id, amount, type, 
 If(amount >= 100, 1, NULL) AS flag
FROM trans JOIN customers  ON (user_id = cust_id)
JOIN bank ON (trans.bank = bank.id)
WHERE (error is false)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

> I tried your table structure in my local and it is working perfectly.
>   I need one thing from you is in which table you are having error column.
>   If I comment where condition then it is working fine.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting fewer rows than you expect, it's either due to:

1. **Join condition**
   You're doing a `INNER` joins to the `customers` and `bank` tables.  If you have 4 source rows in your `trans` table, but only one row that matches in your `customers` table (condition `user_id = cust_id`), then you will only have one row returned.

   The same goes for the subsequent join to your `bank` table.  If there you somehow have a transaction that references a bank which is not defined in the `bank` table, then you won't see a record for this row.
2. **WHERE clause**
   Obviously you won't see any rows that don't meet the conditions specified here.

It's probably #1 -- check to see if the rows with `payment_id IN (1,3,4)` have corresponding `user id` values in the `user` table and corresponding `bank id` values in the `banks` table.